# nginx server connecting to docker containers running laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I need to configure an nginx server to connect to multiple docker networks for different projects. As of now, I am trying to connect nginx to one docker network.

The docker network has php (laravel) and mysql in two different containers.

Here is the nginx configuration:

```
upstream web {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name tinyurl.abc.org;
    root        /home/azureuser/app/url-shorterner/public;

    ssl_certificate      /home/azureuser/app/certs/abc.org.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/azureuser/app/certs/abc.org.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  error;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  web;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /tinyurl/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name tinyurl.abc.org;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The docker-compose.yml file has the following:

```
version: '3.8'

# Services
services:

  # Web (Application) Service
  web:
    build:
      context: ./.docker/web
      args:
        HOST_UID: $HOST_UID
    container_name: tinyurl-web
    ports:/
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www/html'
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  # MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
    container_name: tinyurl-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
      MYSQL_HOST: '${DB_HOST}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10

  # Scheduler Service
  scheduler:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia:latest
    container_name: tinyurl-scheduler
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./.docker/scheduler/config.ini:/etc/ofelia/config.ini
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

The problem seems to be in the routing of the request. The index.page within the public folder of laravel shows up, but none of the other static pages are showing up. Also, the routing of the requests is not happening correctly.

Looks like the fastcgi configuration is not okay.

Can anyone help with this, and point me to what needs to be done to the nginx configuration to route to the web container having laravel.

With Regards,
Sharat

Comment: Try changing `fastcgi_pass  web;` to `fastcgi_pass  web:9000;`

Comment: I tried that, but get the following error:

nginx: [emerg] upstream "web" may not have port 9000 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tinyurl.conf:34

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx config, replace 127.0.0.1 with the service name in your docker-compose

```
upstream web {
    server web:9000;
}

server {
   ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  http://web;
   ...
```

Comment: I tried that, but get the following error:

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:9000" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tinyurl.conf:2

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I have some similar setups running locally via docker-compose like this

Comment: Still giving me an nginx error - nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:9000" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tinyurl.conf:2.   When I run "docker ps", the docker containers show up as follows:


CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                                       NAMES
...
d347f29c7fd5   tinyurl_web              "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   tinyurl-web
...

Comment: I tried changing web to tinyurl_web which is the Docker Image Name, but that does not help